# Install an IPA through USB?

Tags: objective-c, ios, installation, xcode4.2

After using the "iPhone Configuration Utility" program to install IPA applications to my iPhone on the go, I wondered how this process worked. Within a few Google searches, I found out about "MobileDevice.framework" and the "MobileDevice Library" connected to it. After reading an article of all the Known Functions in the library, I found one called "AMDeviceInstallApplication". I thought this would work once I saw install, but I'm currently perplexed on how to use it.

**TL;DR** I have IPA files and I want to make an Xcode program (for Mac) that installs the IPA's application to a connected iOS device when a button is pressed.

Also, don't worry about the application not being signed correctly. It is signed with a provisioning profile installed on devices [the application] will be used with.

Comment: ...anyone? Sorry, would like to get this working..

Answer (score 2):

If you're still interested in this problem I've written a blog entry on how to install apps on a connected iPad / iPhone without using Xcode or iTunes.

This method allows you to run a Terminal command to install an iPA file.

http://pervasivecode.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/install-ios-app-ipa-file-without-xcode.html

I suppose you could bundle up the terminal commands in your application and use it that way?

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to start the application as well using this library or other tools? I would like to automate the process of running UI tests on my device from my build server at night.

Comment: These command-line tools can't do this unfortunately. I believe it's possible to launch apps if you connect via lldb (the debugger that Xcode uses internally), have never tried this myself though.

Comment: I'll try that, but I'm struggling to find any info about it :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way to install iPa file to real iPhone or iPad:

Connect iPhone to Mac via USB and follow the below steps:

**Steps to follow:**

1. Open Xcode
2. Click on Window
3. Select Devices and Simulators
4. Drag and drop the IPA files into it
5. App got installed on the iPad